# Do i need to delete a object that was constructed with new and placement

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator, placement-new

```
class Foo{
//some member
    public:
    int bar;
}

int main(){
    char* buffer = new char[100];
    Foo* f = new(buffer)Foo();
//do i have to
    delete f;
//or is 
    delete[] buffer;
//enough
}
```

Sure i have to delete it if the delete of `Foo` has some major effect on the system but lets say it is a simple storage object which i place which is compleatly inside of the buffer and has no deconstructor which does delete some other things.

- Do i have to delete a object which where places with the new inside
  of a buffer or is it enough to delete the buffer?
- If i have to call delete on every object inside of the buffer, why do
  i have todo this?

I read: [what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) and he also says

> You should not deallocate every object that is using the memory buffer. Instead you should delete[] only the original buffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to destroy that object is with an explicit destructor call:

```
f-> ~Foo();
```

Usually placement new is used with memory on the stack. In this case, it's heap allocation, so you do need to free the buffer using the form of `delete` that matches the `new`.

```
delete[] buffer;
```

Comment: So if i use placement i need to call the destructor explicit. But the question is why i need todo this and does it even matter if its stack or heap? Well sure if its heap i need to call delete, but does it matter to the `~Foo()` call i need todo?

Comment: @BennX: `f->~Foo()` seems no-op in your case, but if you have `std::string` in `Foo` for example, it is no longer true and you will have leak.

Comment: @BennX Placement new separates allocation from initialization. Essentially, since you created the object using two steps, destroying it requires the opposite two steps. `delete f` might work in practice, because the pointer values happen to match up, but it's undefined behavior: not guaranteed to work. Better to be tidy and correct than terse.

Comment: @Jarod42 I got it. Sure i need to call the delete in this case. But if i only have simple types? (In the case where i want to use it it only contains simple types)

Comment: In that case, the `~Foo()` is a no op, and the compiler will optimize it away.

Comment: @Potatowatter thanks for this short and simple explenation. But does it matter if the class only has simpletypes? Doesnt they are at the spot where i created it and should be deleted with the buffer delet?

Comment: @BennX If the type is trivially destructible, it doesn't matter whether you call the destructor or not — by definition. Even for `std::string`, you're not actually required to call the destructor, to obtain a correct program. C++ does permit you to leak the memory.

Comment: @Potatoswatter So i am right, that if it only contains types which are "really" inside the buffer, it doesnt matter and i dont need to call the destructore explicit only delete the buffer? (so no dynamic structures) In the end it is really important that i dont have a memory leak..

Comment: @BennX It doesn't matter, but it also doesn't cost anything to write the destructor call, for the sake of caution.

Comment: @Potatoswatter True it doesnt matter if i always have the handle, but if i only got a weaktype and cast a position to the type it does matter if i have to traverse stepwise over the buffer to check if there is a valid object and if i need to delete it. Thanks alot for the help.